# How get business in area when user give end and start point's latitude and longitude?

Tags: ios, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I want to make project in which user submit starting and ending points' latitude and longitude on first screen. After submitting user get list of all business in between those points on next screen. So that I get latitude and longitude from user, and after getting how show list of all business? Which API provides these two events? I have required method how I show list of business of between these points.

Comment: This differ from other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in api for this type of information. You would have to get it from a third-party provider/server.